# python3からdarknet [yolov3]呼び出し

Tags: python, python3

環境 linux mint18 mate

darknetでyolov3
識別した範囲の画像をキャプチャーしたいのですが、
以前に端末からではなく、pythonから呼び出せば可能だと聞きました。

どの様にして呼び出すのでしょうか？

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/122229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2018年4月20日現在、Python 2 だと [`python/darknet.py`](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/508381b37fe75e0e1a01bcb2941cb0b31eb0e4c9/python/darknet.py) を使えば識別が可能です。ただし以下の変更が必要でした。

1. [チュートリアル](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/)に従って、目的に合った訓練済み重みファイルをダウンロードしておく。
2. 適当な場所からシンボリックリンクを張るなどして、`libdarknet.so` が見えるようにする。
3. そのままだと `tiny-yolo.cfg` を読みにいくので、ここを yolov3 に変える。

また、Python 3 でも更に以下の変更を行うと動くことを確認しました。

1. `print r` を `print(r)` にする。つまり `2to3 -w ./python/darknet.py` 相当のことをする。
2. 文字列の型が変わった関係でファイル名の部分をバイト列にしないと動かないので、すべて `.encode('ascii')` をつける ([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7258112/5989200))。

このサンプルプログラムでは最終的に `r` へ識別結果が入っているため、その後に何か処理したい場合はこの `r` を元に行うことになります。

※ darknet のリポジトリ内容は時折破壊的に変わるため、この方法が将来的にも使えるとは限りません。使えなかった場合、darknet の issue トラッカーを見るなどして、まずはサンプル・プログラムがあるか確認するのが良いと思います。

Comment: python/darknet.py　をdarknetフォルダに入れ、３番を行いprint文を修正しました。  File "ggregs002.py", line 47, in <module>
OSError: libdarknet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
と出ます。文字列の型が変わった部分は何処と何処なのでしょうか？　　darknetファルダに入れたので２番は大丈夫だと思っています。

Comment: 2番が原因です。そのフォルダは .so ファイルのサーチパスに含まれていません。`/usr/local/lib` や `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` についてお調べください。こちらの投稿も参考になるかと思います: ["Why can't Python find shared objects that are in directories in sys.path?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1099981/5989200)

Comment: 相対位置から絶対パスに変更したおかげで実行できました。１５０行目のURLの部分に文字列の前にbを付けることで解消されました。しかし、受け取った値が[(b'bicycle', 0.9941766262054443, (363.4241638183594, 278.7040100097656, 396.94329833984375, 331.8062438964844)), (b'dog', 0.9900424480438232, (221.59780883789062, 380.45477294921875, 186.77037048339844, 312.46099853515625)), (b'truck', 0.9237195253372192, (581.048583984375, 128.2719268798828, 215.67906188964844, 85.07489776611328))]
などの値なのですが、これは、どの様に解釈すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: `detect` 関数の実装が `python/darknet.py` に含まれているので、そちらをご覧ください。

Comment: 分かりました。失礼します。2文字不足